# ERROR EN MYSQL 1881 – Operation not allowed when innodb_forced_recovery > 0

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Estoy tratando de agregar una columna y modificar un campo de my base de datos mysql, hasta ayer funcionaba todo bien, de repente empezo a arrojar ese error. La base esta alojada en un servidor de hosting

Comment: Puedes compartir la definicion de la tabla que estas intentando modificar y el tipo de Engine que estas utilizando para esa tabla

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generalmente este error se produce cuando MySQL está en modo de solo lectura.

Ante todo puedes ejecutar la siguiente instruccion para determinar el valor del parametro innodb_force_recovery:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%innodb_force_recovery%';
```

Tu valor debe ser mayor a 0, en este caso debes ingresar al servidor donde esta instalada tu base de datos y editar el archivo de configuracion /etc/my.cnf.

En este archivo debes comentar la siguiente linea:

```
 # innodb_force_recovery = 1
```

Cuando este parametro esta comentado o no existe en /etc/my.cnf vuelve a la configuración predeterminada de 0, que es lo que necesitas  ya que el error explicitamente muestra que tienes un valor mayor.

Comment: tiene como value = 1. Tengo la base de datos alojada en un hosting que no tiene cpanel

Comment: Si no tienes acceso al servidor donde tienes alojada tu base de datos el hosting debe proveer las herramientas para modificar parametros de lo contrario debes contactarlos para que te sorporten en este cambio. Que hosting estas utilizando?

Comment: argentina-hosting

Comment: soporte@argentina-hosting.com escribe aqui para solicitar soporte a tu hosting. O puedes consultar directamente al hosting desde la siguiente direccion https://www.argentina-hosting.com/consultas. Espero te sirva. Saludos! Recuerda ponderar la respuesta si fue de tu utilidad.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE `express` (
  `id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cod_empresa` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tipo` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `empresa` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `equipo` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tarjeta` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `serie` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `idd` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_orden` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_actividad` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `identificacion` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nombre_cliente` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `direccion` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `localidad` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `codigo_postal` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `provincia` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fecha_creacion` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `telefono1` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `telefono2` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fecha_de_envio` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cartera` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `baja` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_fecha_recolector` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `remito_rend` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `remito_cv` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fecha_rend_cv` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_operador_ren` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_motivo_ren` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `master_box` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_operador` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fecha` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_motivo` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tabla_oper` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MULTIPLES` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cable_hdmi` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cable_av` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fuente` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `control_1` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `otros` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `remito_sub` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fecha_remito_sub` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fecha_asignado` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_recolector` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `operador` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sub_asignado` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ciclo` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `zona` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fecha_premio` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mes_base` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `r1` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `r2` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `r3` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tipo_de_recupero` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `semanas` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ano_semana` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fecha_de_liquidacion` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `hist_pactado` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `estado_rec` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `horario_rec` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `estado_pac` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `horario_pac` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `identificacion` (`identificacion`),
  KEY `serie` (`serie`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```